# I enabled ufw in an aws instance. How to stop that?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, aws, ufw

I enabled ufw within the server instance, when connected through ssh.

But now, I am not able to connect to the server in any way.

Is there a way to disable the ufw in the server?

I couldnt find any way from aws console.

It is a ubuntu server

Comment: A better title for the question would be something about 'How to re-connect to locked out system'.  As it is, it reads like the main point is to stop 'ufw' but if the title was about the broader issue of re-connection then the answers to it would be more searchable for all instances of locked out or otherwise fried systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same sort of thing once; even worse though as I fried the instance so that it couldn't even boot.  What you do is:

1. Boot some other instance.  Anything will do that can mount the system disk
   of your old system.
2. Find the old system disk of your old system on your 'Volumes' tab of the ECs console.
3. Shut down your old instance and detach the system volume from it as per [the aws documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-detaching-volume.html).
4. Attach it to your new instance as per [the aws documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html) as some boring, non-boot drive.
5. Edit the files on it wherein you did the **bad thing** that made it so that you couldn't access it any more.  In your case 'ufw' configuration files.
6. Now go the other way and detach it from your new instance and hook it back up to your old instance as a system disk.
7. Boot your old instance and hopefully you can get to it now.  If not, rinse, repeat.

This method has the advantage that you don't lose any data or configuration work that you might have created between the time that you last did a 'snapshot' of the instance and the time that you fried it.

Answer (score 1):

AWS does not offer "console" access to their virtualized instances; if you have locked yourself out of an instance, your best (and probably only) recourse if you don't have a back door into it that is still viable due to `ufw` getting in the way is probably going to be destroying and redeploying the instance.

Comment: This, however, loses any data or configuration work that occurred between the time that the instance was last backed up via a 'snapshot' and the time that the user got locked out.  Hopefully that's not a long time due to due diligence in backing things up but annoying nonetheless.   Better to detach the system disk from the instance, edit it elsewhere to fix the problem and then re-attach.